# How to remove "Intel Anti Theft device cannot be detected" error message on boot?

Tags: windows-7, boot, sony-vaio, anti-theft

Whenever I boot up the laptop the following error message pop-ups:

```
There is a problem with Intel Anti Theft Device can not be detected*
```

(*not word for word)

I believe that Intel Anti-Theft was uninstalled from my Control Panel (as it is no longer there).

How do I fix/remove this error message from popping up every time the computer boots?

Specs:

> Sony Vaio VPCSC
>   i-core 5 Sandy Bridge
>   Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: Someone stole your anti-theft software 0_o :)

Comment: have you checked whether it is available on the Sony site? (Might be listed as Intel Manager or similar.)

Comment: If it's popping up, something is causing that.  Check Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler to see if there isn't a task there that's raising this alarm.